# Has a 145 minute version of "Salò, or the 120 Days of Sodom" ever been published?

Tags: alternate-version, censorship

The [wikipedia italian](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sal%C3%B2_o_le_120_giornate_di_Sodoma) page says that there is a 145 "original cut" version of the film, I have not been able to find any site that sells it.
I found some sites that refer to it, like [this](http://www.criterionforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=275&start=125), [this](https://www.artforum.com/film/david-velasco-on-pier-paolo-pasolini-s-salo-or-120-days-of-sodom-21050) or [this](https://videologybarandcinema.com/event/midnights-salo-or-the-120-days-of-sodom/).

I'm a little doubtful about its publishing, how can I know if it exists?

---

Comment: The forum you link to mentions that the reels with "outtakes" have been stolen and not yet retrieved; so how do you expect there to be a release of the 145 minute version?

Comment: Wait, I know about the reels that have been stolen but in the link you refer a user says that "Pasolini himself removed 25 minutes to help the pacing"
To help the pacing, not because they have been stolen, futhermore I know that Pasolini used the "double shootings" (i.e. the same scenes from another perspective) in the mounting.
Maybe misunderstood the aforesaid link, I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

25 plus 117 is still not 145. On the double blueray the movie is called "final cut" but length same as Italian censored version BUT contain 155 min of extras.

The final cut version was never digitized as the reels we're stolen during/after Pasolini recut to shorter version (also theorised that Pasolini destroyed them personally).